# Creating a jsonObject that contains another jsonObject

Tags: java, json, android-async-http

I am using asynchttpclient to do a POST and am constructing a body like this:

```
{
  "params": {
                  "firstname": "%Paul%"
            }
}
```

The following sometimes produces the right body, sometimes produces an empty body:

```
 String encodedFirstname = "%" + first + "%";
 JSONObject paramsVal = new JSONObject();
 paramsVal.put("firstname", encodedFirstname);
 String[] keys = { "params" };
 JSONObject postBody = new JSONObject(paramsVal, keys);
```

What do I need to correct?  Thank you.

Comment: Construct an empty object and `put` the other object into it, rather than trying to construct it with the elements in it.  (Reasonably clear from the documentation.)

Comment: Nope, the javadoc has a constructor with jsonObject as the first argument.  Ambiguous.

Comment: But if you look at the documentation, that constructor *extracts* values from the supplied jsonObject -- it doesn't insert the jsonObject in the new jsonObject.

Comment: "Construct a JSONObject from a subset of another JSONObject." - unclear, even after your explanation I don't know what this ctor overload does.

Comment: Exactly what it says: Constructs the new object from the specified parts of the old one.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
JSONObject object1 = new JSONObject();
try {
        object1.put("firstname", "%Paul%");
} catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
JSONObject object2 = new JSONObject();
try {
        object2.putOpt("params", object1);
} catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried using put again and it worked:

JSONObject postBody = new JSONObject("params", paramsVal);

Worst.  Javadoc.  Ever.